# Swift Protocols: Custom Property Setter Crash because of Recursive loop

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Swift: Custom Property Setter Crash because of Infinite Loop

```
public protocol RequestType {
    var parameters: AnyObject? { get set }
}

public extension RequestType {

    public var parameters: AnyObject? {
        get { return nil }
        set { parameters = newValue }
    }

    public printParameters() {
        print(parameters)
    }

}
```

Usage :

```
class HTTPBinRequest: RequestType { }

let request = HTTPBinRequest()
request.parameters = ["name" : "Rahul"]
request.printParameters()
```

It crashes because it is stuck in the recursive loop.

But when i declare the property in the class and leave the setter empty, it just works.

```
class HTTPBinRequest: RequestType { 
    public var parameters: AnyObject?
}

public extension RequestType {

    public var parameters: AnyObject? {
        get { return nil }
        set {}
    }

    public printParameters() {
        print(parameters)
    }

}

let request = HTTPBinRequest()
request.parameters = ["name" : "Rahul"]
```

Could anyone suggest how can i solve this better way.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why do you override the getter and the setter?

Comment: I am creating a library Restofire/Restofire for network requests and i would love this functionality without defining explicitly the variable in your class.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are trying to create a *stored property* in a protocol extension. You can't do that. You can only create *computed properties* in a protocol extension.

Here is a stored property:

```
class A {
    var value: Int?      // Stored property
}
```

Here is a computed property:

```
class B {                       
    var someString: String?     // Stored property

    var value: Int? {           // Computed property
        get { return Int(someString) }
        set { someString = "\(newValue)" }
    }
}
```

The computed property can't set itself - if you try to do that, it creates the recursive loop that you are experiencing. But it can do other things, like set other stored properties of the class, as in the example above which accepts an `Int` as a new value but then stores it as a `String`. The `Int` value itself is never stored. When you retrieve the `Int` value, it computes it from `someString` every time it is accessed.

If you were trying to do this as a protocol, you could put the computed property in the protocol, but not the stored property:

```
protocol BProtocol {
    var someString: String? { get set }
    var value: Int? { get set }
}

extenstion BProtocol {

    var value: Int? {        
        get { return Int(someString) }
        set { someString = "\(newValue)" }
    }
}
```

But then you still need to define the stored property in the class:

```
class B: BProtocol {                       
    var someString: String?
}
```

But you will not need to define the `value` property. `class B` will inherit that from the `BProtocol` extension.

So the short answer to your question is, create the stored property in your class, and not in the protocol extension.

EDIT:

Based on the comments, maybe you need to use a two-tiered protocol. The first protocol sets out the requirements for objects that don't use the `parameters` property:

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
   var someStuff: String? { get set }
}

protocol BaseProtocolWithParameters: BaseProtocol {
   var parameters: AnyObject? { get set }
}
```

I say that because generally it is bad design to have protocols with requirements that require the user to create properties that are never used. If some objects aren't ever going to use `parameters`, then those objects shouldn't be required to conform to a protocol requirement that they don't need. They can conform to `BaseProtocol`. Objects that actually do need to use `parameters` can conform to `BaseProtocolWithParameters` which inherits from `BaseProtocol`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was also able to solve the problem using a stored property. The thing is i am making a library for other developers and as it doesn't have any compile time check so if any users of my library misses out this. Then it will have unexpected behaviour. Is there any way i can add a warning if its being used and they have not added a stored property in the class.?

Comment: They should get a compiler error saying the class doesn't conform to the protocol if they don't add the property

Comment: The compiler will warn them if their class tries to conform to the protocol but it is missing the property that the protocol requires.

Comment: The compiler doesn't warn because the protocol has got the default implementation of parameters. I want them only be declared when they have to be used.

Comment: Practical usage : https://github.com/Restofire/Restofire/blob/6389e70aaf18cbd9242b037c0e2338f558510458/Tests/Core/Services/HTTPBinService%2BGet.swift

Comment: So get rid of the default implementation...it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: If i remove the default implementation then i will have to include it as a stored property in every class i create even if i am not using it because of the compiler warning that it doesn't conform to the protocol. :( I need the default implementation of the getter to be nil by default.

Comment: Your protocol should not have requirements that are not required...maybe you need to break your protocol into two parts - one protocol where `parameters` is required, and one where it is not. See my edited answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help Roman. I was able to generate a warning by remove set in protocol -  public var parameters: AnyObject? { get } and the test case also passed so i don't need to make two separate protocols.